# Info.plist Editor doesn't offer field for keys?

Tags: ios, xamarin, permissions, visual-studio-2017

Visual Studio 2017 offers a new tool / property pane for Info.plist

[image]

It offers all kinds of options, but I don't see any option to set my permissions

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to the camera to take photos.</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to photos.</string>
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to microphone.</string>
```

Is there really no such option and I have to add the keys manually to the Info.plist?

Comment: use text editor to do this,

Comment: Which type of permission do yo want to add? If no option displays there, yes, open with xml editor and add it manually.